# How the exists() method of class File works?

Tags: java, file-io, scjp

Good Morning, i have used these method to check if a certain file exists in a group of directories:

```
public static boolean doesFileExist(String[] directories, String fileName) {
    String path = " ";
    for (String dir : directories) {
        path = path + File.separator + dir;

    }
    System.out.println(path);
    File file = new File(path, fileName);
    return file.exists();
}
```

i give the method an array of directories and a file name which is actually exists in one of them, here's the array of directories:

```
    static String[] direstories = { "B:\\eslam\\xml", "B:\\eslam\\xml\\paper" };
```

and the file `ch23.pdf` does exists in the first directory, i think that the method takes a whole string of a group of directories and split it according to a regex like `/^[A-z]+$/:` but it violates my expectation as the method returns false with these group of directories `\B:\eslam\xml\B:\eslam\xml\paper`

Comment: That's not even remotely how the API works. I suggest you read the JavaDoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the scope of your loop wrong?

You'll only be checking against the last element in your array of directories I think.

Comment: That should be a comment, perhaps!

Comment: Could be - but it also answers why the code isn't doing what the OP expects. The file exists in the first directory, which he'll never actually be checking.

Comment: Isn't the method above checks for the concatenation of the two directories?? it doesn't even check for the last directory as you said and that's what i'm asking about

Comment: The file.exists method does not work in the way that you are hoping. It'll look in the path shown by the System.out.println in your code above ( which will almost certainly not exist in your file system ) for a file called ch23.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The method works only for a single path, actually a file instance should only point to a single file path.

Try this:

```
public static boolean doesFileExist(String[] directories, String fileName) {
for (String dir : directories) {
    System.out.println(dir+ File.separator+fileName);
    File file = new File(dir, fileName);
    if(!file.exists()) return false;
}
return true;}
```

Comment: i don't want a working method, i just want to test the method with the code i have written with no change in sequence

Comment: I see, so the only way I think it would work is this way:
static String[] direstories = { "B:", "eslam", "xml" };